# How to get data from dropdown list into a table in PHP?

Tags: php, list, pdo, dropdown

I have a droplist which has been populated by database. I am trying to fetch data relevant to its table ID. I can fetch the data but it is returning all the data instead of an ID specific to a sport. When I choose a sport from the drop down then click on the button i want to return that data.

I have two files one which is the action and the file which has the dropdown list

```
<form method='POST' action="sportSearch.php">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="dropDownList">
                <select value="sport" name="sport">
                    <?php
                        try {
                            $dropDownSport = $pdo->prepare('SELECT sportName FROM sport');
                            $dropDownSport->execute();
                            $dropDown = $dropDownSport->fetchAll();
                        } catch(PDOException $e) {
                            $error = 'Select statement error';
                            include 'error.html.php';
                            exit();
                        }
                        foreach($dropDown as $row) {
                            echo'<option value='.$row["sportID"].'>'.$row["sportName"].'</option>';
                        }  
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Below I am trying to find id to the specific sport but its just output

```
 $sportId = $_POST['sport'];

$where = "";
$search_sport_id = false;

if(is_numeric($sportId)) {
    $search_sport_id = true;
    $where = "WHERE sport.sportID = :sportID";
}

try {
    $selectSport = $pdo->prepare ('SELECT athlete.athleteID, 
    athlete.eventID, athlete.sportID, athlete.lastName, athlete.firstName, 
    athlete.gender, event.eventName, sport.sportName, athlete.gender, 
    athlete.image, athlete.medal
    FROM athlete JOIN event ON event.eventID = athlete.eventID JOIN sport 
    ON sport.sportID = athlete.sportID '.$where);

    if($search_sport_id == true) {
        $selectSport->execute(array(':sportID' => $sportId));
    } else {
       $selectSport->execute(); 
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'Select statement error';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

Then output to a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>athleteID</th>
        <th>eventID</th>
        <th>sportID</th>
        <th>lastName</th>
        <th>firstName</th>
        <th>eventName</th>
        <th>sportName</th>
        <th>gender</th>
        <th>image</th>
        <th>medal</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        if(!empty($selectSport)) {
            foreach($selectSport as $row) {
                echo'<tr>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['athleteID'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['eventID'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['sportID'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['lastName'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['firstName'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['eventName'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['sportName'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['gender'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td><img src="photos/'.$row['image'].'"</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$row['medal'].'</td>';
                echo'</tr>';
            } 
        } 
    ?>      
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `$row['sportID']` doesn't exist.

Lets look at your query:
`$dropDownSport = $pdo->prepare('SELECT sportName FROM sport');`

You're only selecting 'sportName' from the table. What you want is:

`$dropDownSport = $pdo->prepare('SELECT sportID, sportName FROM sport');`

Two additional things I'd like to point out:

**Debugging in PHP**

Debugging in PHP can be fairly straight forward, especially in this case. What you should of done is echo out `$sportId` after `$sportId = $_POST['sport'];` in your second script - this would of shown you that this was an empty variable. OR you could of used a browsers inspect feature on your dropdown list - it would of shown you that the values were empty.

**Object-Orientated PHP**

One of my biggest hates in PHP is people who avoid using objects. I find them especially useful when it comes to databases. Have a look - it's sure to help you with future issues (IMO Object orientated PHP is easier to debug).